# TypeScript не видит глобальные перемнные

Tags: typescript

/src/types/globals.d.ts

```
declare global {

  interface Window {

    SERVER_ADDRESS?: string;
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,


    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/types/*.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Может нужно так `SERVER_ADDRESS: string;`? Без символа `?`.

Comment: @TemirStack без символа `?` аналогично не работает